# React Native error while building for android - Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, cross-platform, react-native-gesture-handler

Here is the error I'm facing while building the android apk of a branch. (does not happen while building for ios). I have been using react-native-gesture-handler since years on this codebase but never faced this error.

This error started occuring after a pr was merged, but this pr does not contain any android side native change.

Version Info :
react-native-gesture-handler: ^2.3.2
kotlin version in build.gradle: 1.6.10
react-native version: 0.68.5

```
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/saumya/Desktop/latest/lc-app/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.kt: (247, 92): Unresolved reference: TIRAMISU

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
```

Have tried popular solutions for this issue like :

1. using this

```
npm i jetifier
npx jetify
```

2. these are already present in gradle.properties :

```
android.useAndroidX=true  
android.enableJetifier=true
```

but still the issue is not getting solved!

Please share any solutions or ask any info . It will be super helpful.

Comment: May be some version mismatch issue or else you need to update kotlinVersion.
Please check if this helps : https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/2168

Comment: What are the values of complileSdkVersion and targerSdkVersion in build.gradle?

Answer (score 9):

Updating `android/build.gradle` sdk versions works for me:

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    targetSdkVersion  '33.0.0'
    buildToolsVersion = 33
    compileSdkVersion = 33
  }
}
```

Comment: Careful with this! I recommend only updating this when instructed to by a react-native upgrade.. Once I did this manually, and I broke the build for like half of our Android users (it worked fine on the android device I test on) Lesson learned..

Comment: what is `react-native-gesture-handler` version?

Comment: "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0"

Answer (score 7):

This `react-native-gesture-handler` issue seems to be popping up everywhere. There must be a version mismatch in the packages that is leading to this error. You'll have to **update** your entire project and look for breaking changes.

Or, downgrading to react-native-gesture-handler to **version 2.8.0** should work in most cases: `yarn add react-native-gesture-handler@2.8.0`

Answer (score 5):

I change it from:

```
Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU
```

to:

```
Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, react-native-gesture-handler caused issue.

Please try this version.

"react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0"

Answer (score 1):

Updating android/build.gradle sdk versions works for me:

```
ndkVersion = "25.0.8775105"

buildscript {
  ext {
    targetSdkVersion  '33.0.0'
    buildToolsVersion = 33
    compileSdkVersion = 33
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your `react-native-gesture-handler` version?

Comment: @ThinkAndCode it was  "^2.12.0"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-navigation` it's possible that `react-navigation` is expecting an older version of `react-native-gesture-handler` and if you update one you will need to update both.